# Why can't I use linq or extensions when I assign a list to an Expandoobject

Tags: .net

I can find whether an item exists on a normal list as follows:

```
Dim x as new list(of string)
dim result = x.any(function (y) y.length > 4)
```

Returns true or false depending on whether there is any item of more than 4 characters.

However, if I do this:

```
dim e as object = new expandoobject
dim x as new list(of string)
e.items = x

dim result = e.items.any(function (y) y.length > 4)
```

Produces an error message saying any is not an extension method of List.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and whether I can assign a list to an expandoobject and then use extension methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because extension methods are just syntactic sugar. In reality, when you say

> dim result = items.any(Function(y) y.length > 4)

You're really calling a static method on the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class as follows:

> dim result = Enumerable.Any(e.items, Function(y) y.length > 4)

This is automatically translated for you by the compiler. Unfortunately, because you're using a dynamic object, the compiler cannot infer that you're attempting to call the extension method because it doesn't know the type of the `length` property. Therefore, it interprets `Any()` as an instance method, which causes it to fail at runtime since such a method does not actually exist.

Even if you change it to use the explicit syntax above, it won't compile correctly, because the it still doesn't know the type of e.items. Therefore, you would need to cast it.

`Dim result = Enumerable.Any((CType(e.items, List(Of String))), Function(y) y.Length > 4)`

Better idea would be to avoid using a ExandoObject if possible. Linq is meant to perform queries against statically typed objects.

Comment: Thank you - that is very clear.  Its a disadvantage of using dynamic objects that I hadn't seen mentioned before.  Apologies - I can't upvote the answer as I don't have enough points to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you have to cast `e.items` to its proper type:

```
dim result = DirectCast(e.items, List(of String)).any(function (y) y.length > 4)
```